# Z3/SMT-LIB Evaluating function and collecting results

Tags: z3, smt

I'm trying to get some values out of Z3 in a way that it queries all available values automatically:

```
(define-fun-rec out ((p Pkg) (t Time)) (List Bool)
  (ite (< t 0) (as nil (List Bool)) (insert (eval (installed p t)) (out p (- t 1)))))

(eval (out a t-final))
```

Unfortunately this gives me the error `unknown function/constant eval`

I also tried doing the `eval` side effect within the function instead of building a list, but that didn't work either, because I can't sequence statements (eval and the recursive call).

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At [this page](https://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide), I found the following quote:

> The **command** `eval` evaluates an expression in the last model produced by
>   Z3. It is essentially executing the *"function program"* produced by Z3.

Since eval is a `<command>`, it follows that it cannot be used within a `<term>` expression.

---

I believe model-enumeration should be easier using some API interface instead of the [SmtLibv2 format](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/language.shtml), as one can easily write a loop that alternates satisfiability checks with learning of a blocking clause that removes previously find solutions from the search space.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks.

Comment: Note that `eval` is only available after you do a check-sat, and as Patrick mentioned it's a command, not a function. You should model your problem without any reliance on `eval` or `side-effects` as you alluded to. SMTLib is essentially a many-sorted first-order logic: Think pure functional programming instead of effects or eval. If you describe what you are trying to model in more detail, you can get better answers.

Comment: Yes, pure functional programming is great, but I do want to be able to extract the final result. At the moment I am interfacing with Z3 directly via pipes. This is a bit annoying, but I wrote my data churning in Haskell and the SBV bindings were too slow for my time constraints. (I have problems with up to 50 000 variables and SBV's performance started to degrade significantly once I reached a few thousand variables.)